# Unable to get django declared app routes working as pages

Tags: python, django, url, path, routes

I am creating an Django app and am facing issues with routes not being identified. It is the same DJango poll app I am trying to create but the documentation code does not work. Here is my code below:

`djangoproject/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^simpleapp/', include('simpleapp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

`simpleapp/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, request


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

`simpleapp/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /simpleapp/
    # url('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /simpleapp/5/
    url('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /simpleapp/5/results/
    url('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /simpleapp/5/vote/
    url('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

If I un-comment the first url of '' path of `simpleapp/urls.py` code, all the pages shown are '' path. However, if I keep the url '' path commented, then the routes give me the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/simpleapp/34/
Using the URLconf defined in simple_django.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^simpleapp/ <int:question_id>/ [name='detail']
^simpleapp/ <int:question_id>/results/ [name='results']
^simpleapp/ <int:question_id>/vote/ [name='vote']
^admin/
The current path, simpleapp/34/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I was unable to get the `path()` imported using `django.conf.urls` or `django.urls`. `url()` was successful. I am using python version 3.6.7 and Django version 2.1.5. What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using path syntax, not regexes, in your simpleapp/urls.py. Change it to:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
  path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
  path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Your project URLs are using regexes, so you shouldn't change those, although you might want to make them consistent.

Comment: Thanks. `I was unable to get the path() imported using django.conf.urls or django.urls. url() was successful. I am using python version 3.6.7 and Django version 2.1.5.` What am I missing? Documentation at docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03 I have tried removing regex and it did not work.

Comment: I doubt very much you are using 2.1. If `from django.urls import path` doesn't work then you are probably using 1.11 or before.

Comment: Daniel, Added image of versions for django and python. It is the same version

Comment: But that only shows you have Django installed for Python 3. Are you actually using Python 3 to run your site? For instance, the boilerplate comment at the top of your urls.py only mentions `url()`, whereas the one you get with 2.1 only mentions `path()`.

Comment: Ok fair enough. let me try uninstall and reinstall django. give me a moment

Comment: That won't help, you need to ensure that you use Python 3 to actually run the server.

Comment: Thanks. Just uninstalled and reinstalled django. I am using python3 command based run. Didnt work. Images attached.

Comment: But now you should be able to import `path`.

Comment: Yes. Cool. Worked. I owe you a treat someday, if we meet.

Answer (score 1):

You define routes like **Django 1.x**

```
url(r'^simpleapp/', include('simpleapp.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

This is Django 1.x type route definition

In Django 2 you must define routes  like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

In Django 2 routes define without regular expression

See docs for route define in **Django 2**

Comment: Thanks. `I was unable to get the path() imported using django.conf.urls or django.urls. url() was successful. I am using python version 3.6.7 and Django version 2.1.5. What am I missing?` Documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: Cool. Removing regex did not work. I am unable to get `from django.urls import include, path` working. I do get `url` though